# How to identify whether an email is read receipt response or not using headers

Tags: email, email-headers

I am just learning about read receipts. I wonder how to identify whether a mail is read receipt response or normal reply?
I surfed the internet and got some header from RFC.
Are those the only way to identify them. Is it possible for a read receipt response to be without these headers. If so, how to identify that it is a read receipt response.

Thanks.

Comment: If something lacks those headers then it is not a well-defined read receipt. Second guessing if something might still try to be something when it is not seems pointless, and slightly superstitious.